# not getting textfield value of "query" from html to php using jquery in load more script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script in php and jquery which allows us to display 3 record from mysql database. When I click load more buton then it show 3 more records. It is working well but i have some problem passing sql query of "index.php" to another file "getData.php"

I have tried to add query textfield in "index.php" and passed it to "script.js" file but it shows error.

"Config.php"

```
$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "tutorial"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//getdata.php

<?php

// configuration
include 'config.php';
$row = $_POST['row'];
$rowperpage = 3;
$query8 = $_POST['query8'];
$query8 = str_replace("order by id asc limit 0,3", "", $query8);


// selecting posts
$query8 = "$query8. limit $row $rowperpage";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query8);

$html = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    $shortcontent = substr($content, 0, 160)."...";
    $link = $row['link'];

    // Creating HTML structure
    $html .= '<div id="post_'.$id.'" class="post">';
    $html .= '<h1>'.$title.'</h1>';
    $html .= '<p>'.$shortcontent.'</p>';
    $html .= '<a href="'.$link.'" class="more"     target="_blank">More</a>';
    $html .= '</div>';

}

echo $html;
// index.php
<?php
include "config.php";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Load more data using jQuery,AJAX, and PHP</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">             

</script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <?php

            $rowperpage = 3;

            // counting total number of posts
            $allcount_query = "SELECT count(*) as allcount FROM      
            posts";
            $allcount_result = mysqli_query($con,$allcount_query);
            $allcount_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($allcount_result);
            $allcount = $allcount_fetch['allcount'];

            // select first 3 posts
            $query = "select * from posts order by id asc limit     
             0,$rowperpage ";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $content = $row['content'];
                $shortcontent = substr($content, 0, 160)."...";
                $link = $row['link'];

            ?>
                <!-- Post -->
                <div class="post" id="post_<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $shortcontent; ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="more"     
                    target="_blank">More</a>
                </div>

            <?php
            }
            ?>

            <h1 class="load-more">Load More</h1>
            <input type="text" id="row" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" id="all" value="<?php echo $allcount;             
               ?>">
            <input type="text" id="query8" value="1">           

        </div>
    </body>
</html>


//script.js
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Load more data
  $('.load-more').click(function() {

    var row = Number($('#row').val());
    var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
    var query8 = Number($('#query8').val());
    // problem with only the variable query8 which is not goes to getdata.php
    row = row + 3;

    if (row <= allcount) {
      $("#row").val(row);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'getData.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          row: row
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          $(".load-more").text("Loading...");
        },
        success: function(response) {
          // Setting little delay while displaying new content
          setTimeout(function() {
            // appending posts after last post with class="post"
            $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
            var rowno = row + 3;
            // checking row value is greater than allcount or not
            if (rowno > allcount) {
              // Change the text and background
              $('.load-more').text("Hide");
              $('.load-more').css("background", "darkorchid");
            } else {
              $(".load-more").text("Load more");
            }
          }, 2000);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('.load-more').text("Loading...");
      // Setting little delay while removing contents
      setTimeout(function() {
        // When row is greater than allcount then remove all     class='post' element after 3 element
        $('.post:nth-    child(3)').nextAll('.post').remove().fadeIn("slow");
        // Reset the value of row
        $("#row").val(0);
        // Change the text and background
        $('.load-more').text("Load more");
        $('.load-more').css("background", "#15a9ce");
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: try to use console.log during develp

Comment: You are sending "row", but where do you use or send the "query8" variable? It seems that in your JS, you initiate the variable and then not use it.